# Creating an isosceles triangle in C3

Tags: c#

The code below only makes a right angle triangle, how would I make it into an isosceles triangle?

```
int height = 4;
string star = "";
for (int i = 0; int i < height; i++)
{
    star += "*";
    Console.WriteLine(star);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

This only displays a right angle triangle. What I attempted to make was a pyramid.

Comment: Why dont you show your compiling code?

Comment: @ Tim  Schmelter I don't understand what you mean by that

Comment: @ Mong Zhu I mean a pyramid's front face.

Comment: @Panther_Yens: What he means is that your code doesn't compile. As an example `For` isn't a valid keyword, it would be `for`. So what Tim is suggesting is that when you say "This only displays a right angle triangle" that you are wrong because *this* doesn't actually compile. I'm struggling to think of any reason why you wouldn't have just copy and pasted your code into this question and thus having valid compiling code...

Comment: As for the question itself - it would be worth saying why you think it should display anything other than a right angle triangle. ie what about your code makes you think that it would generate an isosceles triangle? Also you can perhaps share the output that you are expecting in this case too... I'm not sure how you would expect an isosceles triangle to work with one star on the first row and two on the second - how would they line up in a console that uses fixed width characters?

Comment: Did you try my code?

Comment: @ Chris I didn't have my laptop with me. You shouldn't get so flustered because of a capital letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have a cleaner code:

```
int numberoflayer = 4;
int empty;
int number;
for (int i = 1; i <= numberoflayer; i++)
{
    for (empty = 1; empty <= (numberoflayer - i); empty++)
        Console.Write(" ");
    for (number = 1; number <= i; number++)
        Console.Write('*');
    for (number = (i - 1); number >= 1; number--)
        Console.Write('*');
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This draws your christmas tree:

```
int height = 4;
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    int countSpaces = (int)Math.Ceiling((height * 2 / 2d) - i);
    int countStars = 1 + (i * 2);
    string line = new string(' ', countSpaces) + new string('*', countStars);
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dirty code but there you go

```
int height = 4;
string empty = "    ";
String star = "";
for(int i = 0; i<height; i++)
{
    star += " *";
    empty = empty.Length > 0 ? empty.Remove(0,1) : " ";
    Console.WriteLine(empty + star);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```